# Camel service endpoints. requestBody cast to string error

Tags: xml, service, request, apache-camel, endpoint

I have set up a simple HTTP service with an endpoint and, which serves up XML repsonses. I am running a JUnit test against the service. Here is an extract from the code below.
The getMessageBody converts a file using a buffered reader to a string.

String src = getMessageBody(xmlname);

```
        MockEndpoint mock = this.context.getEndpoint("mock:resultsCheck",MockEndpoint.class);
        mock.expectedMessageCount(2);

        LOG.info(".. get response object");
        Object responseBody1 = this.template.requestBody("cxf://bean:Port",src);
        String responseBody2 = this.template.requestBody("cxf://bean:Port",src, String.class);
```

The problem is that the line:

Object responseBody1 = this.template.requestBody("cxf://bean:Port",src);

works fine and returns a populated object.

This line returns null and I am not sure why:

String responseBody2 = this.template.requestBody("cxf://bean:Port",src, String.class);

Any ideas?

-- Edit --

I have investigated a little further and it seems to be a problem with the type conversion. A suitable conversion cannot be found from type org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus to org.apache.camel.Component

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

On the 2nd call, do the CXF web service return a non-empty response?

You can try to comment out the 1st call, so you do only the 2nd call, and see if you get a response.

Also what type is the Object which is returned from the 1st call. And if you execute it's toString method, does it return null?

Comment: The webservice returns the same object. Possibly a problem with the actual casting then?..

Tried commenting out the 1st call and still have a null response.

The type of the object returned matches the proxy class we have set up in the config

Comment: Using the toString method on the Object returns just the object type name